# Allow folder in all AppArmor profiles?

Tags: apparmor

I want to put all my modified ubuntu server configurations files (/etc/...) in one folder via symbolic links. However, it's annoying having to write the same line in all apparmor profiles.

Is there a way to allow this folder on all apparmor profiles?

Comment: Allow this folder? Apparmor isn't that simple. What *exactly* do you want to do? What steps have you taken? You created a folder and then symlinked everything in /etc/ to it? Please *edit* your question with this information.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you'll be including the base abstraction in each profile, edit that:

Add `/etc/* r,` to `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/base` and make sure `#include <abstractions/base>` is in every profile.

However, `/etc/* r,` (or whatever you're linking to) will be one line anyway. Either way you have to add a line.

I have no idea why you would want to do this, however.

You could also create a template with everything you need already defined.